# Is there a way to print a pointer with %x argument

Tags: c

I have tried to make a program with the parameter %d in a pointer but it does not work, I changed  to %p, but that is for the address, I want to print the value.
This is the error

```
gcc null_Pointer.c -o null_Pointer
null_Pointer.c: In function ‘main’:
null_Pointer.c:7:35: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
    7 |    printf("The value of ptr is : %x\n", ptr  );
      |                                  ~^     ~~~
      |                                   |     |
      |                                   |     int *
      |                                   unsigned int
      |                                  %ls
```

this  is the  code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   int  *ptr = NULL;

   printf("The value of ptr is : %x\n", ptr  );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `%p`.

Comment: and cast the argument to `void *`, assuming you want to print the address held by the pointer.

Comment: What output do you see? And what output did you expect?

Comment: You would derefrence `ptr`, to print the value, like this: `*ptr`.  If it's not pointing to a valid `int` address though you'd invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: "I changed to %p but that is for the address, I want to print the value" in your example you definitely try to print the pointer itself what is exactly what is meant by *the address*. *The value* would be `*ptr`, what would invoke UB in your case `ptr == NULL`.

Comment: What are you expecting to be printed in your code?

Answer (score 4):

To print the value that the pointer points to, you have to dereference it with `*`.

```
printf("The value of ptr is: %d\n", *ptr);
```

But this will cause undefined behavior if `ptr` is `NULL`, you have to assign it to point to a valid `int`.

```
int a = 123;
int *ptr = &a;
```

Then it will print `123`.

Answer (score 2):

To print the address value stored in `ptr`:

```
printf( "The value of ptr is %p\n", (void *) ptr );
```

The print the value of the thing `ptr` *points to*:

```
printf( "The value of what ptr points to: " );
if ( !ptr )
  printf( "(null)\n" );
else
  printf( "%d\n", *ptr );
```

If `ptr` is `NULL`, this code will print the string `(null)`.  If `ptr` is not `NULL` but otherwise *invalid* (doesn't point to an `int` object within that object's lifetime), then the behavior is undefined.  You may get garbage output, you may get a runtime error, "The Lonely Goatherd" may start playing out of your computer, etc.  There's no good way to test if a non-`NULL` pointer is valid, which is why it's a good idea to set unused pointer objects to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The format string defines both: what kind (type) of value is expected and how it will be printed, then the corresponding argument needs to correspond.

If you chose `%p` the expected value must be of pointer type and will be printed in hexadecimal format. From the man:

> `p` The void * pointer argument is printed in hexadecimal

If you want to print the value a pointer points to, then:

1. your pointer must point to something
2. you must dereference the pointer with operator *
3. use any suitable format character

In your case, `%d` can be used to print an `int` in decimal format. From the man:

> `d`or `i`  The int (or appropriate variant) argument is converted to signed
>                decimal (d and i)

To met the three criteria you can write something like:

```
int a = 666; // define an int variable
int *ptr;    // define a pointer to an int (actually not initialized)
ptr = &a;    // make the pointer points to the int named a, or, make the pointer takes the value of the address of variable a
print("%d\n",*ptr); // print as decimal the value pointed by ptr
```

If you want to print the value pointed by `ptr` in hexadecimal, then use `%x`.

Answer (score 0):

The proper format specifier for printing a pointer value is `%p`.  You also need to cast the pointer to `void *` because `printf` doesn't know the exact type of the parameters it receives.

```
printf("The value of ptr is : %p\n", (void *)ptr);
```

Regarding your comment:

> I changed to %p, but that is for the address

That's correct, and the address in question is the value of `ptr`.